# Can I search/get file by using File ID in Dropbox V2 API?

Tags: dropbox, dropbox-api

I'm using Dropbox V2 APIs (C#) to get files/folders from Dropbox account. I am able to fetch particular file/folder by using its specific path. I wanted to know whether there is any way I can fetch file/folder by using ID?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This depends on exactly which operation(s) you're referring to. For example, downloading files and getting metadata for files or folders support specifying file IDs:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-download
https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-get_metadata

You would specify the `path` as a string like "id:a4ayc_80_OEAAAAAAAAAYa".

Searching and listing folders currently do not support this though:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-list_folder
https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-search

The same applies to the corresponding methods in the SDKs.

---

Edit: [list_folder](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-list_folder) and [search](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-search) now do support file IDs.

Comment: Thank you very Greg.
  I wanted to get the metadata of file/folder by using ID and as you suggested with #files-get_metadata it is possible.